# typedef в лямбда-выражениях

Tags: visual-c++, typedef, c++11, c++, lambda

Недавно обнаружил странный "баг" или "недофичу" в реализации лямбда-функций vs2010:

```
template< typename Anc >
class A : public Anc{
  //
  typedef SomeJobClassSpec  JOB;
  //
  void something(){
    std::for_each(
      Some.begin(), Some.end(), []( SOME&x ){
        new JOB::TASK( ... ); // ошибка: JOB не определен!!!
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Решение:

```
template< typename Anc >
class A : public Anc{
  //
  typedef SomeJobClassSpec  JOB;
  //
  void something(){
    std::for_each(
      Some.begin(), Some.end(), []( SOME&x ){
        typedef JOB _JOB;
        //
        new _JOB::TASK( ... ); // OK!!!
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Выходит, `typedef` в лямбдах видит несколько больше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это, должно быть, баг VS 2010.

У gcc-4.7.2 проблем с похожим кодом нету: http://ideone.com/Pi6slP.